# Remove the positive terminal button of an AA battery?

Tags: battery-operated, repair

I was thinking of doing a simple repair: replacement of a NiMH AA battery in a device I own, but it uses a battery without any protruding positive terminal (no room to spare). I can't really find any new such batteries that are easily available to me. I only need the one and I would feel stupid importing a single AA battery if I can avoid it.

I'm wondering if there's an easy method to convert an ordinary commercial cell, i.e. remove the positive terminal button, which would still allow for soldering (or spot welding)? I doubt that flattening it with compression is a good idea, and the only alternative I can think of is to file it down, or, if it's loose, pull it out with pliers. Would that work?

Comment: look for a battery with tabs instead.  Not available in stores, but can be had all over the internet.

Comment: @Aaron Yeah, maybe. But by the time I've shipped one single AA from another country it'll have felt needlessly slow, expensive, and environmentally wasteful ‍♂️

Comment: That wasn't part of the OP.  :)

Comment: @Aaron It's been fixed ↑

Comment: Environmentally friendly = leave the original battery in place.

Comment: @Andyaka And buy an entire new product? Brilliant.

Comment: Your question struck me as wanting to change the design of a product to use a different battery technology. This is a design Q and A site.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm unsure about whether you're objecting to the question, or just explaining your suggestion. I'll assume the latter. Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm doing a repair of an existing device, which was tagged but, granted, not very prominent. I'll make it more clear in the Q.

Comment: > soldering  <br> Do not solder to a cell: it will damage it. Only use spot welding.

Comment: The AA battery is manufactured in China or Taiwan and shipped to the other side of the world anyway so I don't see what you would be gaining. Get yourself a battery with soldertabs and be done with it.

Comment: @winny I am aware of where it's manufactured — doesn't mean we all have to go there separately and individually package each battery every time we need one. I'll be gaining: time, price, knowing whether this is possible, and how to do it in the future. If it were possible it would literally take minutes to convert one and have it in my hand. Why create your own PCBs when you can just buy them finished from China and be done with it?

Comment: With more experience, you probably will. I only do custom circuit/PCB designs when there isn’t a suitable commercial offering. Anyway, not buying suitable  component X because of Y is not an engineering question.

Comment: @winny You're right, it's not an engineering question, because it's not a question. I've also never focused on that aspect so I don't know where you got that from. My actual question, on the other hand, is regarding how to physically adapt a component according to my own criteria, and it apparently isn't a topic or question you're interested in moving forward (because you're too experienced, have lots of time and money to waste, or whichever off-topic point you're trying to make) so why hang around? You don't see what I'm gaining, yes, we know that by now — but that's neither here nor there...

Comment: It’s an XY question. You want to know if you can cut off the tab of an AA battery but the real problem is replacing the battery. No you can’t. You’ll need to get a battery with solder tabs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The “button” is formed into the top metal part (it’s never solid, that would be too expensive) and filing it off will destroy the battery seal, as will your more violent suggestions. Damaging the seal will allow the electrolyte to escape. Image from [here](https://www.panasonic-eneloop.eu/es/file/basis-construction-01jpg).

[image]

You can source an appropriate cell or perhaps salvage one from an existing battery pack with welded tabs. NiMH cells have a limited shelf life though, at least in my experience.

Comment: That's interesting. My idea came from looking at these: http://lygte-info.dk/pic/Batteries2013NiMH/Ladda%20AA%202000mAh%20(Green-Silver)/DSC_6321.jpg which seemed to have holes at the side of the button, suggesting to me that they were a separate part. I guess they might be an exception of some kind.

Comment: If you’re not afraid of damaging the cell or if you have extras you can always sacrifice one to science and see if I am wrong! If there is a valve and small holes visible for a vent it might be a good idea not to obstruct the vent, explosion-wise.